# QVariantAnimation loop animation CPU usage

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6, qvariantanimation

I am trying to animate the background of a frame in a loop, so it changes from color1 to color2 to color1 etc.

Here is what I have so far which is working but it is eating 2-3% of my CPU which I think it should not:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self._animation = QVariantAnimation(self.ui.frame)
        self._animation.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.setEndValue(QColor(55, 25, 99))
        self._animation.setStartValue(QColor(120, 214, 159))
        self._animation.setDuration(1000)
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self._animate)

        self.animate_timer = QTimer()
        self.animate_timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.animate_timer.timeout.connect(self.add_animation)

    def add_animation(self):
        if self._animation.direction() == QAbstractAnimation.Forward:
            self._animation.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        else:
            self._animation.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()

    def _animate(self, color):
        qss = "QWidget#frame {background-color: " + color.name() + ";}"
        self.ui.frame.setStyleSheet(qss)
```

I believe there should be a more elegant way which won't cause this CPU usage, but I could not figure out. The problem is I have a pretty high end CPU and if it does 2-3% on this CPU it will cause more on some slower CPUs where we will run this program. If I don't do animation it is 0%.

Comment: What you say is strange, what are the characteristics of your machine? What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10, i7-7820X, 32GB ram, and I am running the app in PyCharm. I am still not sure if this would be the best way to run the loop animation with that timer and start it every second backward or forward, it was just a quick idea. I would not care about that 1-2% but I know that it will run on much slower PCs so I need to figure out something.

Comment: Have you tried not to run it from pycharm but from cmd?

Comment: It is the same, however I noticed that if I change the animation duration to like 500ms and the timer is 1000ms, the CPU is now around 0.5%. It might be that the animation is not over yet but the timer starts it again as they had the same duration (1s). If I set the animation duration to 900ms to make the transition smoother it goes to 1% CPU, strange. Any idea how to make it looping without the timer which might overlap the animation?

Comment: @ZoltanSzabo I can see ~2%, but I have an old i5-3570K (linux). Note that: 1. continuously updating the stylesheet requires some time, especially if the widget has many children that would eventually check if the parent's stylesheet change affects them; 2. if you only want to override the background color of a frame, you can use a subclass (by promoting the widget) and eventually draw the background on your own by overriding the `paintEvent()` (you could consider setting the palette `Window` role, though); 3. for continuous cycling, use `self._animation.finished.connect(self.add_animation)`.